# Problem with start react application project

Tags: reactjs

`failed to load config from C:\Windows\system32\react-aplication\vite.config.ts error when starting dev server: TypeError: Cannot redefine property: File at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>) at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Windows\system32\react-aplication\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\index.js:7:8) at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14) at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10) at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32) at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12) at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19) at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18) at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Windows\system32\react-aplication\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\helpers\config-api.js:16:14) at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)`

This is what i have in my console when i want to start 'dev' and after i start by commend npm run dev

'Couse i want to lern

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.